# Flex PrintAdvancedDataGrid need something similar to sizeToPage for columns

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, printing, advanceddatagrid

I have an AdvancedDataGrid that's pretty wide (lots of columns that need to be wide enough to read) that I need to print.  The PrintAdvancedDataGrid.sizeToPage property adjusts the height of the grid so that page breaks only occur between rows.

I'm looking for something similar for columns.

Here's a test case (main program, FlexBuilder 4.5)

```
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.printing.FlexPrintJob;
            import mx.printing.FlexPrintJobScaleType;

            protected function btnPrint_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                doPrint();
            }
            private function doPrint():void {
                var printJob:FlexPrintJob = new FlexPrintJob();

                if (printJob.start()) {
                    printJob.printAsBitmap = false;

                    var thePrintView:PrintView = new PrintView();
                    thePrintView.includeInLayout = false;
                    addElement(thePrintView);

                    thePrintView.height = printJob.pageHeight;

                    thePrintView.myDataGrid.source = myGrid;

                    thePrintView.validateNow();

                    // This example doesn't have that many rows, 
                    // so I'm skipping the extra code to handle "multiple pages"
                    printJob.addObject(thePrintView, FlexPrintJobScaleType.NONE);

                    removeElement(thePrintView);
                }
                printJob.send();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <fx:Array id="data">
            <fx:Object c1="c1r1" c2="c2r1" c3="c3r1" c4="c4r1" c5="c5r1" c6="c6r1" c7="c7r1" c8="c8r1" c9="c9r1" c10="c10r1" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r2" c2="c2r2" c3="c3r2" c4="c4r2" c5="c5r2" c6="c6r2" c7="c7r2" c8="c8r2" c9="c9r2" c10="c10r2" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r3" c2="c2r3" c3="c3r3" c4="c4r3" c5="c5r3" c6="c6r3" c7="c7r3" c8="c8r3" c9="c9r3" c10="c10r3" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r4" c2="c2r4" c3="c3r4" c4="c4r4" c5="c5r4" c6="c6r4" c7="c7r4" c8="c8r4" c9="c9r4" c10="c10r4" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r5" c2="c2r5" c3="c3r5" c4="c4r5" c5="c5r5" c6="c6r5" c7="c7r5" c8="c8r5" c9="c9r5" c10="c10r5" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r6" c2="c2r6" c3="c3r6" c4="c4r6" c5="c5r6" c6="c6r6" c7="c7r6" c8="c8r6" c9="c9r6" c10="c10r6" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r7" c2="c2r7" c3="c3r7" c4="c4r7" c5="c5r7" c6="c6r7" c7="c7r7" c8="c8r7" c9="c9r7" c10="c10r7" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r8" c2="c2r8" c3="c3r8" c4="c4r8" c5="c5r8" c6="c6r8" c7="c7r8" c8="c8r8" c9="c9r8" c10="c10r8" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r9" c2="c2r9" c3="c3r9" c4="c4r9" c5="c5r9" c6="c6r9" c7="c7r9" c8="c8r9" c9="c9r9" c10="c10r9" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r10" c2="c2r10" c3="c3r10" c4="c4r10" c5="c5r10" c6="c6r10" c7="c7r10" c8="c8r10" c9="c9r10" c10="c10r10" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r11" c2="c2r11" c3="c3r11" c4="c4r11" c5="c5r11" c6="c6r11" c7="c7r11" c8="c8r11" c9="c9r11" c10="c10r11" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r12" c2="c2r12" c3="c3r12" c4="c4r12" c5="c5r12" c6="c6r12" c7="c7r12" c8="c8r12" c9="c9r12" c10="c10r12" />
        </fx:Array>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Button id="btnPrint" x="0" y="0" label="Print" click="btnPrint_clickHandler(event)"/>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="myGrid" top="30" dataProvider="{data}">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c1" width="200" />
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c2" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c3" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c4" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c5" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c6" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c7" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c8" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c9" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c10" width="200"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

---

And here's the PrintView.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:VBox xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
         backgroundColor="0xffffff">

    <!-- The sizeToPage property is true by default, so the last
    page has only as many grid rows as are needed for the data. -->
    <mx:PrintAdvancedDataGrid id="myDataGrid"  height="100%" horizontalCenter="0">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c1" width="200" />
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c2" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c3" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c4" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c5" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c6" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c7" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c8" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c9" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c10" width="200"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:PrintAdvancedDataGrid>
</mx:VBox>
```

When you run this and press the Print button, you'll see the grid printed across 4 pages.  That's a good thing - in my real app, I need the grid that wide.  My concern is that the page breaks are splitting columns in a very ugly way.

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more generalized solution.  In the production code the original grid gets columns added dynamically, so the previous answer won't work.  Also, I don't need all those extra PrintView objects.  (It's good to have one for headers & footers).

Here's the main code:

```
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.printing.FlexPrintJob;
            import mx.printing.FlexPrintJobScaleType;
            import mx.printing.PrintAdvancedDataGrid;

            protected function btnPrint_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                doPrint2();
            }
            private function doPrint2():void {
                var printJob:FlexPrintJob = new FlexPrintJob();

                if (printJob.start()) {
                    printJob.printAsBitmap = false;

                    var thePrintView:PrintView = new PrintView();
                    thePrintView.includeInLayout = false;
                    addElement(thePrintView);
                    thePrintView.height = printJob.pageHeight;

                    var columns:Array = new Array();
                    var colWidth:Number = 0;
                    for (var colIndex:int = 0; colIndex < myGrid.columns.length; colIndex++)
                    {
                        var aColumn:AdvancedDataGridColumn = myGrid.columns[colIndex] as AdvancedDataGridColumn;
                        if (colWidth + aColumn.width < printJob.pageWidth) {
                            columns.push(aColumn);
                            colWidth += aColumn.width;
                        } else {
                            thePrintView.grid.columns = columns;
                            thePrintView.grid.dataProvider = myGrid.dataProvider;
                            thePrintView.validateNow();
                            // This example doesn't have that many rows, 
                            // so I'm skipping the extra code to handle "multiple pages"
                            printJob.addObject(thePrintView, FlexPrintJobScaleType.NONE);
                            removeElement(thePrintView);

                            columns.length = 0;
                            columns.push(aColumn);
                            colWidth = aColumn.width;

                            thePrintView = new PrintView();
                            thePrintView.includeInLayout = false;
                            addElement(thePrintView);
                            thePrintView.height = printJob.pageHeight;
                        }
                    }
                    if (columns.length > 0)
                    {
                        thePrintView.grid.columns = columns;
                        thePrintView.grid.dataProvider = myGrid.dataProvider;
                        thePrintView.validateNow();
                        // This example doesn't have that many rows, 
                        // so I'm skipping the extra code to handle "multiple pages"
                        printJob.addObject(thePrintView, FlexPrintJobScaleType.NONE);
                        removeElement(thePrintView);
                    }
                }
                printJob.send();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <fx:Array id="data">
            <fx:Object c1="c1r1" c2="c2r1" c3="c3r1" c4="c4r1" c5="c5r1" c6="c6r1" c7="c7r1" c8="c8r1" c9="c9r1" c10="c10r1" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r2" c2="c2r2" c3="c3r2" c4="c4r2" c5="c5r2" c6="c6r2" c7="c7r2" c8="c8r2" c9="c9r2" c10="c10r2" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r3" c2="c2r3" c3="c3r3" c4="c4r3" c5="c5r3" c6="c6r3" c7="c7r3" c8="c8r3" c9="c9r3" c10="c10r3" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r4" c2="c2r4" c3="c3r4" c4="c4r4" c5="c5r4" c6="c6r4" c7="c7r4" c8="c8r4" c9="c9r4" c10="c10r4" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r5" c2="c2r5" c3="c3r5" c4="c4r5" c5="c5r5" c6="c6r5" c7="c7r5" c8="c8r5" c9="c9r5" c10="c10r5" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r6" c2="c2r6" c3="c3r6" c4="c4r6" c5="c5r6" c6="c6r6" c7="c7r6" c8="c8r6" c9="c9r6" c10="c10r6" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r7" c2="c2r7" c3="c3r7" c4="c4r7" c5="c5r7" c6="c6r7" c7="c7r7" c8="c8r7" c9="c9r7" c10="c10r7" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r8" c2="c2r8" c3="c3r8" c4="c4r8" c5="c5r8" c6="c6r8" c7="c7r8" c8="c8r8" c9="c9r8" c10="c10r8" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r9" c2="c2r9" c3="c3r9" c4="c4r9" c5="c5r9" c6="c6r9" c7="c7r9" c8="c8r9" c9="c9r9" c10="c10r9" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r10" c2="c2r10" c3="c3r10" c4="c4r10" c5="c5r10" c6="c6r10" c7="c7r10" c8="c8r10" c9="c9r10" c10="c10r10" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r11" c2="c2r11" c3="c3r11" c4="c4r11" c5="c5r11" c6="c6r11" c7="c7r11" c8="c8r11" c9="c9r11" c10="c10r11" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r12" c2="c2r12" c3="c3r12" c4="c4r12" c5="c5r12" c6="c6r12" c7="c7r12" c8="c8r12" c9="c9r12" c10="c10r12" />
        </fx:Array>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Button id="btnPrint" x="0" y="0" label="Print" click="btnPrint_clickHandler(event)"/>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="myGrid" top="30" dataProvider="{data}">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c1" width="200" />
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c2" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c3" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c4" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c5" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c6" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c7" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c8" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c9" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c10" width="200"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

The PrintView is as before.  The actual column definitions are irrelevant.

```
    <!-- The sizeToPage property is true by default, so the last
    page has only as many grid rows as are needed for the data. -->
    <mx:PrintAdvancedDataGrid id="grid"  height="100%" horizontalCenter="0">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c1" width="200" />
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c2" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c3" width="200"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:PrintAdvancedDataGrid>
</mx:VBox>
```

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't intend on answering my own question, but I found an answer & hopefully this will help someone else.

The solution is to use multiple PrintAdvancedGrid objects, and to set the columns of each as needed.  I'll post this answer with my first solution, then another with a more general approach.

In this one, I assumed a fixed number of columns in the original grid.

Here's the main file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" >

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.printing.FlexPrintJob;
            import mx.printing.FlexPrintJobScaleType;
            import mx.printing.PrintAdvancedDataGrid;

            protected function btnPrint_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                doPrint();
            }
            private function doPrint():void {
                var printJob:FlexPrintJob = new FlexPrintJob();

                if (printJob.start()) {
                    printJob.printAsBitmap = false;

                    var thePrintView:PrintView = new PrintView();
                    var pv2:PrintView2 = new PrintView2();
                    var pv3:PrintView3 = new PrintView3();
                    var pv4:PrintView4 = new PrintView4();

                    thePrintView.includeInLayout = false;
                    addElement(thePrintView);
                    pv2.includeInLayout = false;
                    addElement(pv2);
                    pv3.includeInLayout = false;
                    addElement(pv3);
                    pv4.includeInLayout = false;
                    addElement(pv4);

                    thePrintView.height = printJob.pageHeight;
                    pv2.height = printJob.pageHeight;
                    pv3.height = printJob.pageHeight;
                    pv4.height = printJob.pageHeight;

                    //thePrintView.myDataGrid.source = myGrid;
                    thePrintView.grid.dataProvider = myGrid.dataProvider;
                    pv2.grid.dataProvider = myGrid.dataProvider;
                    pv3.grid.dataProvider = myGrid.dataProvider;
                    pv4.grid.dataProvider = myGrid.dataProvider;

                    thePrintView.validateNow();
                    pv2.validateNow();
                    pv3.validateNow();
                    pv4.validateNow();

                    // This example doesn't have that many rows, 
                    // so I'm skipping the extra code to handle "multiple pages"
                    printJob.addObject(thePrintView, FlexPrintJobScaleType.NONE);
                    printJob.addObject(pv2, FlexPrintJobScaleType.NONE);
                    printJob.addObject(pv3, FlexPrintJobScaleType.NONE);
                    printJob.addObject(pv4, FlexPrintJobScaleType.NONE);

                    removeElement(thePrintView);
                    removeElement(pv2);
                    removeElement(pv3);
                    removeElement(pv4);
                }
                printJob.send();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <fx:Array id="data">
            <fx:Object c1="c1r1" c2="c2r1" c3="c3r1" c4="c4r1" c5="c5r1" c6="c6r1" c7="c7r1" c8="c8r1" c9="c9r1" c10="c10r1" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r2" c2="c2r2" c3="c3r2" c4="c4r2" c5="c5r2" c6="c6r2" c7="c7r2" c8="c8r2" c9="c9r2" c10="c10r2" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r3" c2="c2r3" c3="c3r3" c4="c4r3" c5="c5r3" c6="c6r3" c7="c7r3" c8="c8r3" c9="c9r3" c10="c10r3" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r4" c2="c2r4" c3="c3r4" c4="c4r4" c5="c5r4" c6="c6r4" c7="c7r4" c8="c8r4" c9="c9r4" c10="c10r4" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r5" c2="c2r5" c3="c3r5" c4="c4r5" c5="c5r5" c6="c6r5" c7="c7r5" c8="c8r5" c9="c9r5" c10="c10r5" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r6" c2="c2r6" c3="c3r6" c4="c4r6" c5="c5r6" c6="c6r6" c7="c7r6" c8="c8r6" c9="c9r6" c10="c10r6" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r7" c2="c2r7" c3="c3r7" c4="c4r7" c5="c5r7" c6="c6r7" c7="c7r7" c8="c8r7" c9="c9r7" c10="c10r7" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r8" c2="c2r8" c3="c3r8" c4="c4r8" c5="c5r8" c6="c6r8" c7="c7r8" c8="c8r8" c9="c9r8" c10="c10r8" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r9" c2="c2r9" c3="c3r9" c4="c4r9" c5="c5r9" c6="c6r9" c7="c7r9" c8="c8r9" c9="c9r9" c10="c10r9" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r10" c2="c2r10" c3="c3r10" c4="c4r10" c5="c5r10" c6="c6r10" c7="c7r10" c8="c8r10" c9="c9r10" c10="c10r10" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r11" c2="c2r11" c3="c3r11" c4="c4r11" c5="c5r11" c6="c6r11" c7="c7r11" c8="c8r11" c9="c9r11" c10="c10r11" />
            <fx:Object c1="c1r12" c2="c2r12" c3="c3r12" c4="c4r12" c5="c5r12" c6="c6r12" c7="c7r12" c8="c8r12" c9="c9r12" c10="c10r12" />
        </fx:Array>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Button id="btnPrint" x="0" y="0" label="Print" click="btnPrint_clickHandler(event)"/>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="myGrid" top="30" dataProvider="{data}">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c1" width="200" />
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c2" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c3" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c4" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c5" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c6" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c7" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c8" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c9" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c10" width="200"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Each of the 4 PrintView objects is similar, differing only in which columns are displayed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:VBox xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
         backgroundColor="0xffffff">

    <!-- The sizeToPage property is true by default, so the last
    page has only as many grid rows as are needed for the data. -->
    <mx:PrintAdvancedDataGrid id="grid"  height="100%" horizontalCenter="0">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c1" width="200" />
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c2" width="200"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="c3" width="200"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:PrintAdvancedDataGrid>
</mx:VBox>
```

The others are similar and not worth posting - just change the values in the `<mx:columns>`.